# How to Comment out Math Equations from a Tex Document PDF output?

Tags: pdf, comments

I want to get a document for proofreading but want to exclude all math equations (including math from inline mode, display mode and equation environments) from the PDF version. What is the best way to do that? I don't want to use comments as I may have to add and remove them each time when I am shuffling from editing to proofreading mode.
Thanks